# Span SQL Rows over time

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, ranking

I have a table with this structure:

- id: int
- data: int
- created_at: timestamp

But this table has approx. 1m rows and I cannot show this on a line graph, Is there a way to get certain rows that are distributed evenly across time? For example, say I only wanted 45 rows from the last 90 days, evenly distributed. I also must add that it is possible that I don't have data for the last 90 days. Therefore I would like to grab as much data as possible. Would it be more efficient to have a ranking system?

Comment: I have found a simple solution but I don't know if it's very effective: `FLOOR(created_at / sample_size)` and I would generate a reasonable sample size based off of oldest `created_at`

Comment: You're essentially trying to get a random sample of Y rows which are distributed from the last X number of days?

Comment: Correct. I am just not sure how to sample a certain number of Y rows that way.